# how can i get coordinates of arbitrary side in sqare something image in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, coordinates

I'm trying to get coordinates of billiards table's side point.
[This is origin image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4GoY.jpg)
in this image to

[This black point's coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsz2x.png)
This black point's coordinates

because i need to get edge's coordinates even when something hide some part of the image, like that way if i can get two arbitrary points in one side of table i can calculate the edge points.
but i have no idea how can i get that point...
please help. thanks for reading

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: this is our team's project github https://github.com/gkalstn000/capstone

we tried 
detecting every lines of images with some threshold and find most closest point of line to whole images upper side, right side, left side, down side..
but it's accuracy is really low.. and doesn't work when people hide some parts of imgs...
sorry for bad english